# Alert won't hide | jQuery

Tags: jquery, alert

I wrote code which will loop through an array, and check values with value that user wrote in input field. If written value exist in array, jQuery needs hide Bootstrap dismissible alert, if value doesn't exist jQuery will show alert.
Code Works when value doesn't exist, but if it exist, it won't hide alert. Why?

```
                    <div id="_hsync_skin_direkt_warn" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign" style="text-transform: none;"></span>Ime i prezime Vašeg lika nije po zadanim normama. Za više informacija posjetite našu <a href="#" target="_blank" title="Klikni da otiđeš na FAQ stranicu.">FAQ</a> sekciju.
                    </div>
                    <br />
                </div>

    $("input[name=_hsync_skin_direkt]").on('change', function() {
    $.each(_hsync_muski_skinovi_rasaB, function(index, value) {
        if(_hsync_muski_skinovi_rasaB[index] == $('input[name=_hsync_skin_direkt]').val())
        {
            $('#_hsync_skin_direkt_warn').hide();
        }
        else $('#_hsync_skin_direkt_warn').show();
    });
});
```

Comment: Check what `_hsync_muski_skinovi_rasaB[index]` returns?

Comment: Your if/else won't work if a non-match occurs after a match because it will just show the alert again. You'll need to use a boolean value to set to true if there is a match and run the if/else after the loop completes, or use `$.inArray` to see if the value exists in the array.

Comment: I didn't stop each function. I fixed it. Thanks!